# HTML input value change

Tags: php, html, input

I have a PHP update page in which I am showing a text field containing a value from the database. It is like this, and it is working,

```
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="text_box" value="<?php echo $row['title']?>"/>
```

Now I need to put this updated value back in the database! I have used the code like this, but it's not updating:

```
$title=$_POST['title'];
$v_id = $_GET['v_id'];
$sql = mysql_query("update vehicles set title = '$title' where v_id = '$v_id'");
```

In detail... an input field is there. It's showing a value contained in `$title` (retrieved from the database) and that value is to be edited and updated.

From my side my code is working perfectly without showing any error, but the value that I give `$title` is giving the same one without any change.

Is there any other way to show a value in an input field without putting in a "value" tag?
Two things wants to happen in a single input field!

Comment: Why are you mixing `$_POST` and `$_GET` like this?

Comment: Bobby tables sends regards.

Comment: Are you running the code only on postback?

Comment: In case @The Scrum Meister wasn't obvious, please *please* **please** read up on SQL injections.

Comment: @ignacio, was just typing that. ---
@OP - Are you having a problem updating your database OR are you having a problem getting data and displaying it in your inputbox?

Comment: I don't understand why @user618124 has not verified that v_id is coming through to the server side as expected. Do developers forget simple debugging?

Comment: @Stephen most PHP err.. developers just have no idea of debugging. PHP is enthusiast's language in the first place.

Comment: @Col Shrapnel  wow, just wow.

Comment: @JohnP just briefly check questions under PHP tag. There are not a single **answer** that assumes or explains debugging. Just shooting in the dark.

Comment: @Col Shrapnel, yes well that just means PHP users who come to SO have very poor skills. Seeing as how it's a Q&A site, hardly fair to tar us all with the same brush. But I do get your point, too much chaff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to post your form HTML as well.

Unless your form looks like the following, that code won't work

```
<form method='post' action='page.php?v_id=1'>
   <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="text_box" value="<?php echo $row['title']?>"/>
</form>
```

This is because you're using $_GET to get the id field and $_POST to get the value field

**EDIT**
Your edit has muddied the water a bit more. I'm going to assume all you want to do is show a title and let the user update the title

```
<?php
   if ($_POST) {
        $title = mysql_escape_string($_POST['title']);
        $id    = intval($_GET['v_id']);
        $sql   = "update vehicles set title = '$title' where v_id = '$id'";
        mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$sql);
   } 
   if (isset($_GET['v_id'])) {
       $id      = intval($_GET['v_id']);
       $sql     = 'SELECT title FROM vehicles WHERE v_id = ' . $id;
       $rs      = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$sql);
       $row     = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
       $title   = htmlspecialchars($row['title']);
   }
?>

<form method='post' action='?v_id=<?php echo $id?>'>
   <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="text_box" value="<?php echo $title ?>"/>
   <input type='submit' value='update'>
</form>
```

This should work for you. I haven't error tested obviously, but the idea is sound. You should also add any other input screening you feel necessary.

Comment: Do u undestand what im trying to do that i wanna show the title before update in a single input tag, after that i wanna edit that and update it

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. By 'show the title' do you mean grab the existing one from the DB? Can you list out the steps that you want to happen?

Comment: yup, that's fine. Definitely using this script as is very dangerous.

Comment: Thaxxx Budy @ last i found the answer

Comment: Nice answer! Although the SQL UPDATE lines seems identical to the OPs version... So what was wrong? Just curious and trying to learn something myself :)

Comment: It's exactly the same thing, I think the OP just didn't have the rest of it  coded properly (the SELECTs)

Answer (score 0):

You are using both `$_POST` and `$_GET`.
Depending on the `method` element value of `<form>`, you need either `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

If this is not helping, please show more code so it is possible to determine which one you need.

Also, you can try to update the database without reading the form, to check if the updating itself is working correctly.

Comment: It *is* possible to mix `$_POST` and `$_GET`... if you know what you're doing.

Comment: True, but I supposed/assumed that in this situation it is unintended. Hence my question for more example code.

Comment: the basic stuff are working perfektly i wanna send the new value insted of $title to DB

Comment: You need to update your question and add more information. Right now it is impossible to give more helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

> is there any other way to showing a value in a input field without putting a "value" tag?

Nope.
That's exactly what `value` attribute for.
What's wrong with it?

only thing to mention, it should be not `<?php echo $row['title']?>` but

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['title'])?>
```

Comment: his working perfectly but i cant edit this value and resend it !! if i edit and save even its taking the old value !!

Comment: no query is working i want to know a input field wanna show a value but wanna send before it want to be edit

Comment: @user618124 please rephrase your last comment

Comment: Sorry guys I dont no how to explain u guys by the way thaxxx alot