# How to change a input value with PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have the following:

```
<div>
    <label>NAME:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="John">
</div>
```

How can I change the `value="John"` from the input with PHP?
Is there any PHP set commands that does that?

Comment: I think you'll find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102487/html-input-value-change

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language. It can not interact with your site in real time or react to user input.

You can however change the value on the server-side to some url-paramters or database entries your server knows about.

```
<div>
    <label>NAME:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="
        <?php
            echo $someVariable;
        ?>
    ">
</div>
```

If you are still interested:

The PHP server will not send any PHP code to the client. It will execute it and send the result to the client. The client doesn't know the difference between a string that got printed by PHP and just a normal string.

The client will not see a difference between

```
 <div>
     <?php echo "Hello World";?>
 </div>
```

and

```
<div>
    Hello World
</div>
```

Have a great day!
If you need further assistance let me know (:

Comment: I have done something like that, my problem is, after I set the value like you did here:
<div>
    <label>NAME:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="
        <?php
            echo $someVariable;
        ?>
    ">
</div>
I want to empty the value after running a function.

Comment: Then like Salvatore Leto mentioned earlier look into
[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102487/html-input-value-change)